# AppleScript handler not working when called from within tell Finder block

Tags: error-handling, applescript, handler

Learning to work with handlers in AppleScript I've run into an issue.  Currently I have trimmed my application to call a handler when ran but currently I get an error:

```
error "Script Editor returned error -1708" number -1708
```

When I compile I have no issues.  When I try to research for a solution I'm unable to find a reason why this doesn't work under the application Finder.  To memory, I recall the `on run` must be declared last in the application.

**the code:**

```
on checkForRebels(tieFighter, starDestroyer)
    display dialog "dark enough" as text
end checkForRebels

on run
    tell application "Finder"
        set the starDestroyer to (choose folder with prompt "Please select the Destroyer")
        set tieFighter to items of starDestroyer
        checkForRebels(tieFighter, starDestroyer)
    end tell
end run
```

I tried searching for

> applescript items throw error when passing to handler

but I returned Apple's [Working with Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html) which doesn't answer my question.  When I review Apple's documentation [About Handlers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html) I don't see anything disclosing what the issue should be.

When I modify my script to:

```
on checkForRebels(tieFighter, starDestroyer)
    display dialog "dark enough" as text
end checkForRebels

on run
    tell application "Finder"
        set the starDestroyer to (choose folder with prompt "Please select the Destroyer")
        set tieFighter to items of starDestroyer
    end tell
    checkForRebels(tieFighter, starDestroyer)
end run
```

it works without any issue but why does the handler `checkForRebels()` not work in application Finder's tell block?  When I call a handler do I have to always do it outside of an application for it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are calling a handler from within a tell block or other handler, you need to specify "my", otherwise it is looking for that command in the Finder dicitonary.

```
my checkForRebels(tieFighter, starDestroyer)
```

From the Applescript Language Guide [Calling Handlers in a tell Statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW1):

> To call a handler from within a tell statement, you must use the
>   reserved words of me or my to indicate that the handler is part of the
>   script and not a command that should be sent to the target of the tell
>   statement.